# Re-Install Windows 7 with bitlocker on hard-drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, bitlocker, windows-installer

I have laptop with WIN 7 Enterprise and installed bitlocker. Now I want to re-install win 7.

It's possible or disc will not allowed me to install new copy of win7?

If I can't, can I somehow remove bitlocker (I don't have any password or PIN)? Or only way is to plug in new hard drive to my laptop and then install win 7?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to be able to boot from CD/DVD/USB then you should be able to do a clean install of the OS but rather than be able to format the existing drive you will first need to get the Windows installer to delete the BitLocker partition where you'll be installing Windows.

Comment: during the installation win7, will be there option to format disc? as usually the option was always available during installation (win xp as example)

Comment: If there are partitions on the disk you will need to delete these if the space they utilise is more than what else is available for the Windows 7 installation. Because the partition is encrypted it will not be accessible by the installer so it doesn't know that it can "format" it, so you can only delete it. If the whole disk is encrypted then there will be one large partition that you'll need to delete. Once deleted you'll be able to create the necessary ones for your fresh install of Windows 7. Windows 7 is a file-based install so you first create the partition and then copy the files.