# Is it possible to install Linux over a windows 10 bitlocked device?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bitlocker

My work gave me a laptop to use in my free time in any way I want. The problem is that bitlocker is enabled and no one in my company knows the password of the account or has any way to disable the bitlocker.

I want to ultimately reinstall Windows but to reset it. I need the decryption key.

That is why I wonder if I can just install Linux (Ubuntu or something) on the drive instead which would maybe just get rid of Windows, and then I can just install a clean version of W10 afterwards.

I do not care about losing the data.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't need the BitLocker password to delete all partitions on an HDD and install Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-Install Windows 7 with BitLocker on hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1085995/re-install-windows-7-with-bitlocker-on-hard-drive).  The answer to this question is applicable to this question.